# How to handle exception in java

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Im working on spring mvc app. My problem is when I call delete method in dao by controller class, exception is not handle in dao. but if I use try catch around calling method in controller it'll catch the error.

controller class method:

```
customerDao.delete(id);
```

Rapository class:

```
public void delete(long id)
{
try{
em.remove(em.find(id));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
//not come to here
}
}
```

If I use try catch around "`customerDao.delete(id);`" handle error.
Why I cant handle exception in dao class.
Note : Exception thrown is child record found unexpectedrollbackexception

Comment: can we see your `delete()` function? There are a kind of exception in Java (`RuntimeException`) which do not needs to be inside a `try-catch` block. It'll throw until a `catch`. I think, if you try to handle the exception in the `delete` function, it'll work.

Comment: What exact exception is thrown? Are you sure it is thrown from inside your `delete()`-method and not when committing? Please post the full stacktrace, it will answer those questions.

Comment: integrity constraint <constraint name> violated - 
                   child record found unexpectedrollbackexception 
I don't have exact code now. this is the problem happen in work place.

Comment: As I said exception is catch in controller  class,but not in dao class.
Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EntityManager.remove does nothing immediately - the transaction commit forces JPA to flush its statements to the database, which is when you will get exceptions.  If you want to handle the exception in your DAO, add in em.flush(); within the try block.  This will force the statement to the database and throw any exceptions immediately.